# Resetting index of columns in pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have written a code to convert rows into columns for a particular order. Everything runs fine but the index of the columns is not right. I am adding the code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('UNT_Data.csv', low_memory=False)
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(' ', '_')

#making index for every change period
df['idx'] = df.groupby('GR_Key').cumcount()

#converting index column name to Change_Period_Start_
df['date_idx'] = 'Change_Period_Start_' + df.idx.astype(str)

#converted the columns to one row for one GR Key
date = df.pivot_table(index='GR_Key', columns='date_idx', values='Change_Period_Start', aggfunc='first')
```

Here is the screenshot of the same:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/spCIU.png)

Answer (score 0):

First remove converting column to strings with prefix:

```
df['date_idx'] = 'Change_Period_Start_' + df.idx.astype(str)
```

And then change `columns` to `idx` and add [`DataFrame.add_prefix`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.add_prefix.html):

```
date = (df.pivot_table(index='GR_Key', 
                       columns='idx', 
                       values='Change_Period_Start',
                       aggfunc='first')
          .add_prefix('Change_Period_Start_'))
```